# How can I install on an Asus EEE PC 900

Tags: installation, 12.04, boot-failure

I have an ASUS eee Pc 900 with original SSD broken.
I want install ubuntu on the SD card.
I use an USB pen drive as installation media.
The setup process start, but stop after few seconds without messages.
There are some parameter to set for start succesfully?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to hear that you are experiencing issues with the installation process of Ubuntu, but I would need to get some more information to help troubleshoot the problem and assist you further with this... At what stage of the installation does it fail? Did you burn the disc image correctly? Using what tool? Please provide me this information in a new reply.

Thank you for your valuable time and your great patience.

Comment: The eee PC 900 do not have CD so I use "Startup disk creator" in another PC to create a USB pen drive for the installation from the alternate ISO. The eee pc boot correctly, I choose the correct language and start the installation process. After few seconds the system stop to responding with black screen